# adding returned value into arrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, return

I am lost in code. I am trying to add a returned value into an ArrayList. The returned value is printed and I have tried to cast it so I can add it to an ArrayList. But nothing seems to be working.

I am in `public void getHeap()` and like to retrieve the `return` value from `public double remove()` to add in an ArrayList. It keeps on telling me `source not found`. Any help?

Thanks!

```
public class MinHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    List<E> h = new ArrayList<E>();
    ArrayList<Double> arrayPostingsList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public void getHeap() {
        MinHeap<Double> heap = new MinHeap<Double>(new Double[]{0.5015530788463572, 0.5962770626486013, 0.4182157748994399});

        ArrayList<Double> newArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        System.out.println();


        while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(heap.remove());
            newArray.add(heap.remove());
        }

    }

    public double remove() {
        E removedNode = h.get(0);
        E lastNode = h.remove(h.size() - 1);
        percolateDown(0, lastNode);

        return (Double) removedNode;
    }

    public MinHeap() {
    }

    public MinHeap(E[] keys) {
        for (E key : keys) {
            h.add(key);
        }

        for (int k = h.size() / 2 - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            percolateDown(k, h.get(k));
        }
    }

    public void add(E node) {
        h.add(null);
        int k = h.size() - 1;
        while (k > 0) {
            int parent = (k - 1) / 2;
            E p = h.get(parent);
            if (node.compareTo(p) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
            h.set(k, p);
            k = parent;
        }
        h.set(k, node);
    }

    public E min() {
        return h.get(0);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return h.isEmpty();
    }

    void percolateDown(int k, E node) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include the stack trace of the error; also indicate in your code the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: Is there suppose to be two `remove` methods? Cause you example won't compile

Comment: Please post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). The code you posted does not compile. You have 2 remove methods defined.

Comment: Please include your error message and stacktrace as well

Comment: I removed one `remove` method.

Comment: `newArray.add(heap.remove());` in the  `getHeap` method is the problem. But how do I add the value in the ArrayList otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `remove()` twice:

```
while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(heap.remove());
    newArray.add(heap.remove());
}
```

On the final iteration, when there's only one item left, the second call will fail.

I think your intention is:

```
while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
    final Double removed = heap.remove();
    System.out.println(removed);
    newArray.add(removed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is it. If I understand it correctly, by using `final` it is taking the values once the `remove` method is finished?

Comment: The `final` keyword just means that the variable cannot be reassigned.  I'm in the habit of making everything immutable unless it needs to be modified, but it doesn't affect the behaviour here at all.  Have a Google for immutable objects, e.g.: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02183/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
public E remove() {
    E removedNode = h.get(0);
    E lastNode = h.remove(h.size() - 1);
    percolateDown(0, lastNode);
    return removedNode;
}
```

Also, I think `arrayPostingList` should be of type `E`, not explicitly `Double`.

Comment: `arrayPostingList` doesn't seem to matter if it is type `E` or not. I have removed one of the two same methods though.

Comment: But did you try augmenting both arrayPostingList and the remove method like @Jim_Garrison said? It's a combo deal.  ALSO btw your code to print remove and print, then remove Again and add to the list, will probably intro an unexpected result